# Liquebase itself generates the file search path from the .csv file data

Tags: postgresql

Tell me, has anyone encountered a problem when you try to fill a table with data via a csv file through liqubase, then springliquebase takes some data from the file and tries to find this file. When
"о " is data from the csv file. How to prevent this?

I tried to remove this line from the file, but liquebase takes the next one and does the same. The result is the same.